# MVC creating 'folders' and sub-folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET WebForms (well,  HTML to be honest)  we could reference pages within folders. EG, my structure could be (in regards to folders only)

root -> MyProductsFolder -> Shoes -> Ladies

And my website would show

```
www.mysite.com/MyProducts/Shoes/Ladies/Page.aspx
```

In MVC, we use a controller and it would appear that we can only ever have 1 level (folder) deep.
Is this right?

Without using URL rewriting, is it possible to have

```
www.mysite.com/MyProducts/Shoes/Ladies/Page
```

I assume the only way to do this is in the controller, but I can't create a controller named Shoes/Ladies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MVC routing to created this URL. Your routing table is usually found in your **AppStart > RouteConfig.cs** class. You can use the route table to create URL maps to your actions in your controllers.

Assuming that MyProducts is your controller, and Shoes, Ladies are variables you want to accept you can do something like:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyProducts", 
    "MyProducts/{category}/{subcategory}/Page", 
    new { controller = "MyProducts", action = "Index" });
```

Note that your routes should be in order of most to least specific, so add this route above the default route.

When you navigate to /MyProducts/Shoes/Ladies/Page, it will map to your index action result in your MyProducts controller, passing variables for category and subcategory, so your controller will look something like

```
public class MyProducts : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string category, string subcategory)
    {
        //Do something with your variables here.
        return View();
    }
}
```

If my presumption is wrong, you want a view returned just for that URL, your route will look like:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyProducts", "MyProducts/Shoes/Ladies/Page", new { controller = "MyProducts", action = "LadiesShoes" });
```

And your Controller:

```
public class MyProducts : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LadiesShoes()
    {
        //Do something with your variables here.
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can safely omit the final "/page" on the URL if you want to.

If I haven't covered your exact scenario with the above examples, let me know and I will extend my answer.

**UPDATE**

You can still put your views in a folder structure under the views folder if you want - and then reference the view file location in the controller - in the following example, place your view file called Index.cshtml in Views/Shoes/Ladies/ folder:

```
public class MyProducts : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LadiesShoes()
    {
        //Do something with your variables here.
        return View("~/Views/Shoes/Ladies/Index.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult MensShoes()
    {
        //Do something with your variables here.
        return View("~/Views/Shoes/Mens/Index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Comment: This answers well and suggests that you need to do custom routing in order to get same URL structure which we take for granted with HTML

Comment: This also means that the View I guess can get very large very quickly... When we had folders, it was easier to organise!

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions, you can override the default locations of the views if you want to replicate your folder structure for your view files. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attribute Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) to define the url of each action like below.

```
public class ShoeController : Controller
{
    // eg: /nike/shoes/lady
    [Route("{productName}/shoes/{xxx}")]
    public ActionResult View(string productName, string xxx)
    {
    }
}
```

Routing Attribute offers flexibility and better code organization. You can check the route definition in the same spot.